# store arguments of a function that is pased in my memory function

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a function save the result and input of data passed trough it.
The idea is that it should not run a recently passed function with the same arguments but instead return the old result. But it will run a the same function if its arguments change.

I think that the function is running even when testing

```
memoize = function(func) {
  var result;
  var old_arg={};
  var test = function(x, y){
    if(!(y in x)){return true;}
    else{return false;}
  };

  return function (){
     old_arg.arg= arguments;
     if (test(old_arg, func)) {
       result = func.apply(this, arguments);
       old_arg.result = result;
     }
     else{result = old_arg.result;}
     return result;
  };
};
```

Comment: what you try here: `test(old_arg, func)` if in _test_ function you check `!(y in x)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are couple of issues with the code:

1. Incorrect use of `in` in `test` function. `in` is used to test if a property exists in an object. `test` function rather needs to compare if objects are equal. Use `JSON.stringify()` instead for comparing objects.
2. Incorrect placement of `old_arg.arg= arguments;`. This overwrites old values of arguments and compares new arguments with new arguments.

Here's one of the way of doing it correctly:

```
memoize = function(func) {
  var result;
  var old_arg={arg:{}, result:{}};
  var compareObjects = function(x, y){
    return (JSON.stringify(x) === JSON.stringify(y));
  };

  return function (){
    if (!compareObjects(old_arg.arg, arguments)) {
      result = func.apply(this, arguments);
      old_arg.result = result;
      console.log("new");
    }
    else{result = old_arg.result;console.log("old");}

    old_arg.arg= arguments;
    return result;
  };
};
```

And then test it using:

```
a = function(a) {
  return a + 10;
}

a = memoize(a);

console.log(a(10));   //op: new 20
console.log(a(10));   //op: old 20
console.log(a(12));   //op: new 22
```

Comment: and as you say: if after `a(12)` call `a(10)` again that printed `new 20` instead `old 20`

Comment: @Grundy: yes, thats because we are storing only the last result. This logic can be easily extended to store last n calls by storing result and parameters in a list and check the parameters in the list. I guess this is easily doable.